# Есть предмет который активируется пользователем и он имеет таймер. PHP

Tags: php, разработка-игр

Добрый день, когда-то ещё давно играл в браузерную игру, мобильного типа, так там были предметы которые давались на время, меня интересует как они этот таймер реализовали? Я php плохо знаю, и представить даже не могу, с чего начинать.

Второй вопрос не по теме, но вдруг.

Интересно, если человек активирует предмет, тогда что, программа каждый раз проверяет условие if, типа если if($a == 1){//навык активный}? Или php может может вставлять куски кода записанный на языке php.

Comment: скорее всего реализовали яваскриптом, по первому вопросу.

Comment: При активации предмета в базу записывается `timestamp` того момента, когда истечет таймер действия предмета. При каждой попытке использования предмета проверяется, не достигло текущее время заданного `timestamp`: если нет, то действие выполняется.